# Usage of adal4j api (ADAL) for Java

Tags: azure, adal

I am just trying to use ADAL api for java.

using the PublicClient.java example to get the accesstoken and idtoken

```
      AuthenticationResult result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
                username, password);
        System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("Refresh Token - " + result.getRefreshToken());
        System.out.println("ID Token - " + result.getIdToken());
```

So does the api provides any util classes to do the following

1) How does the id token looks like.Do we need to decrypt it for readable

2) Verifying the json web token:

Meaning I need to verify that the token is valid by passing the privatekey and token to check if its valid

3) Validate the token signature

Then token has header,claimset and signature. How to validate the signature--Any util class available

Any help is really appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late but answering it anyways in case someone needs help with this. Please use msal4j instead of adal4j. adal4j is now deprecated.